# Normal Force - What if I stepped on a molecularly frozen object?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, particle-physics, atomic-physics, molecular-dynamics

I’ve been trying to understand normal force on a molecular level, and I’ve come across the idea that atoms are connected to each other by forces that act like springs. You step on the floor; the floor atoms compress until their ‘spring’ force is equal and opposite to that which you exert on them; this push back upwards on you **allows you to step forward!** This normal force connection to motion applies to more objects, e.g. cars actually move forward **because** the ground’s springy atoms **push back on** the car tires.

I’ve heard that **if normal force didn’t exist**, it would mean that the atoms of an object give way to any force applied to them, and everything would fall through and accelerate toward the center of the earth. This makes sense when you think about a free body diagram: if gravity isn’t counteracted by normal force, then the net force (and acceleration) in the y-direction is downward.

I’m curious about the theoretical possibility of an alternative ‘absence of normal force’ when thinking about it as an object’s ability to push back on another object with spring action (perhaps this is a **sub-question: is a substance’s ability to push back on a force applied by another substance an accurate definition of normal force?**)

What if the theoretical substance ‘diamondite’ was so hard and rigid that it had NO ATOMIC SPRING ACTION at all? Obviously this is completely theoretical; we can’t even say that objects at zero kelvin are rendered atomically ‘frozen’. But if I in theory constructed a floor out of diamondite and then stepped on it, wouldn’t that floor be unable to push back on me? Isn’t this another possible answer to the question **what would happen if normal force didn’t exist?**

I’m wondering what would happen if I stepped on diamondite:

- Would the absence of atomic spring action mean that there cannot be friction and therefore I would just slip on it and then infinitely slide at a constant velocity (or constant acceleration?) across the floor?
- If I put both feet on the floor, would I become stuck to the surface? Since there is no push springing me forward, would I be stuck forever pressing into the floor but never able to move?

Please correct any misunderstandings of the mechanics at work in normal force that you see here.

Thank you!

Comment: The floor would support you. Your molecules would be displaced more than they might otherwise be. Consider stepping on a steel plate vs a trampoline...

Comment: You incorrectly interpret “*NO ATOMIC SPRING ACTION* [sic]” as an absence of a restoring force, but it’s instead the absence of a displacement—the limit of an arbitrarily large stiffness. So the premise of the question doesn’t seem to hold; please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your general concept of a normal force is basically fine; it is the force applied by a body when a force is applied upon it by another body, like the force the ground applies to your feet when you are standing on the surface of the earth, with the original force being gravity.

In your concern about whether the material would have a normal force you are forgetting a very important aspect of the interaction between material objects on the microscopic scale: the electrostatic interactions of the particles. While you are correct to a first approximation that interatomic forces (what chemists call bonds) can be modeled somewhat like springs that will "snap back" if you do not apply so much force as to irrevocably separate them, I want to focus in on your "0 K" scenario, as it raises an important point. Even if the atoms in your hypothetical substance were utterly frozen in a perfect crystal lattice at absolute zero, and the substance has no heat capacity with which to obtain vibrational energy as heat from other sources, the particles that make up your foot (or your shoe or...) would still be strongly repelled by the hypothetical substance due to the Coulomb force at short ranges. Thus, you would still experience a normal force and could still step on this substance. You would not be "stuck" unless this substance were to form an unusually strong attractive interactions with the molecules of your shoe/foot, which does not seem particularly likely.

Note that your concern with not being able to move if you were to stop completely on a surface of your hypothetical substance is also missing a fundamental part of the puzzle of movement: friction. Unless a surface is so utterly free of defects that it is atomically smooth, you will experience significant microscopic friction when your muscles try to move you along a surface. By the conservation of momentum, if one leg moves forward, the rest of you will move backward in turn, with the degree of displacement dictated by the relative mass of your leg and the rest of your body. The difference, however, is that the frictional force (originating in the unevenness of the surface and the electrostatic interactions we mentioned before) applied to your planted foot/shoe will resist this motion and keep your foot essentially in place, allowing your other foot to move forward and letting you to make progress walking along the surface. This is why car tires "stick" to the road and are able to push forward, why you are able to walk on various surfaces, etc. It is also why it is much harder to get moving along a surface with a smaller amount of friction (i.e. ice).

Comment: Thanks Matt! I’m excited to look up the Coulomb force and learn more.